# Beanshell Assertion returns inconsistent results if the loop count is more than 1

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have added a beanshell assertion in the HTTP request and if I run the script with loop count value 1, by adding 1 value in the CSV file, the assertion returns proper result but if I change the loop count to more than 1 Ex:4 and run the script, by adding 4 values in the CSV file (the 1st loop runs the test by selecting 1st value from the csv file 2nd loop selects the 2nd value and so on)  I see inconsistent result with the assertion.

Ex: with 1 loop if the assertion shows the value correctly as 'not checked' if I run the test by adding 3 more values to the csv file by moving the 1st value to 4th row, the assertion shows the value for the 4th row same as the value for 3rd row (though the value for the 4th row supposed to be different from the value for the 3rd row).

Here is the Beanshell assertion I am using:

```
String Response1 = prev.getResponseDataAsString();    
String Response2 = prev.getResponseDataAsString();    
String Response3 = prev.getResponseDataAsString();    
if(Response1.contains("${accInst}") && Response2.contains("${otherInst}") && Response3.contains("${accInstAvailableNotChecked}")){    
Failure=false;    
log.info("In Case ID: ${id}, Account Instructions Available is Not Checked");    
}    
else if(!Response1.contains("${accInst}") || !Response2.contains("${otherInst}") && Response3.contains("${accInstAvailableChecked}")){    
Failure=false;    
log.info("In Case ID: ${id}, Account Instructions Available is Checked");    
}    
else{    
Failure=true;    
FailureMessage="Account Instructions Available is not set correctly in the case.";    
log.error("Bean Shell Assertion is FAIL");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The same code will return the same results given the same input data. If you're getting different results - most probably you're providing different data. Double check all 4 JMeter Variables values using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination, most probably assertion code works fine, you're just providing wrong input data to it
2. Check your Assertion [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), it might be the case the Assertion is being called 2x more times that you expect due to wrong placement in [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) tree
3. Consider accessing JMeter Variables in Assertion code using `vars` shorthand i.e. go for `vars.get("accInst")` instead of `"${accInst}"`
4. [Since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Dimitry. Actually the I was able to resolve the issue by adding the "Default Value" as 'Not Found' in the regular expression extractor. Also I saw the same issue with a different beanshell assertion and was able to resolve it by adding 'Not Found' in the "Default Value" field of the Reg Expression Extractor.

Can someone explain the use of adding 'Not Found' to the "Default Value" field of the reg expression extractor.